# Problem with basics of Kivy (prolly .kv file)

Tags: python, kivy

Can you guys have a look at my python/kivy code?

main.py (copied from video tutorial):

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass

TheLabApp().run()
```

thelab.kv:

```
#:kivy ! 2.1.0

MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Hello"
        size: "200dp", "100dp"
        pos: "100dp", "200dp"
```

Running this code ends up with diffrent results. Sometimes it compiles returning empty window, sometimes it ends up with this (or similar) errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\klaud\Documents\Studia\A Python\test\main.py", line 10, in <module>
     TheLabApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 923, in _run_prepare
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 696, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 372, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 483, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 590, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "C:\Users\klaud\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 569, in execute_directives
     raise ParserException(self, ln, 'Unknown directive')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "c:\Users\klaud\Documents\Studia\A Python\test\thelab.kv", line 1:
 ...
 >>    1:#:kivy
       2:
       3:MainWidget:
 ...
 Unknown directive
```

Code is copied from yt, where it worked just fine. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Remove '**!**' from the directive in the `.kv` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file), the first line of a `.kv` file should be

```
#:kivy `1.0`
```

where `1.0` is the lowest version you support, or simply the version you're currently using. I have version 2.1.0, so my header line is

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
```

without the `!`. That worked fine for me.

Completely removing the header also worked.

Comment: No changes after removing "!". Should I reinstall kivy?

Comment: @DR4NKR1D3R are you sure you're using version 2.1.0? Try just putting `1.0` there and see if that works. If it doesn't, you could certainly try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: It s fine now. I think the VS code was a problem.